# Selecting values from list in dictionary python

Tags: list, python-3.x, dictionary

I've been working on a small contact importer, and now I'm trying to implement a block that automatically selects the output file format based on the number of contacts to be imported.

However, every time it results in the error:

```
KeyError: 'q'
```

I can't figure out for the life of me why this is happening, and I would love any help offered.

My idea of scalability is that the dictionary `personDict` would be of the format `personDict = {nameid:[name,email]}`, but nothing works.

Any help is good help,

Thanks

```
def autoFormat():
    while True:
        name = input("Enter the person's name \n")
        if name == "q":
            break
        email = input("Enter the person's email \n")
        personDict[name] = [name, email]

    if len(personDict) <= 10:
        keyValue = personDict[name]
        for keyValue in personDict:
            for key, value in personDict.iteritems():
                combined = "BEGIN:VCARD\nVERSION:4.0\n" + "FN:" + name + "\n" + "EMAIL:" + email + "\n" + "END:VCARD"
                fileName = name + ".vcl"
                people = open(fileName, 'a')
                people.write(combined)
                people.close()
                print("Created file for " + name)

autoFormat()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that when the user types `"q"` your code leaves the `while` loop
with `name` keeping "q" as value. So you should remove this useless line:

keyValue = person_dict[name]

Since there is no element with key `"q"` in your dictionary.

Also in the export part you write in file values different from those you loop with.
Your code becomes:

```
if len(personDict) <= 10:
    for name, email in personDict.values():
            combined = "BEGIN:VCARD\nVERSION:4.0\n" + "FN:" + name + "\n" + "EMAIL:" + email + "\n" + "END:VCARD"
            fileName = name + ".vcl"
            people = open(fileName, 'a')
            people.write(combined)
            people.close()
            print("Created file for " + name)
```